# How do you fix this input issue on Material UI (MUI-React)?

Tags: google-chrome, material-ui

[image: chrome auto fill overlay on input fields]

The place holder texts (Email address, Password) are overlayed by the Chrome browser's autofill. How do I disable placeholder color to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I turned on "shrink" using `InputLabelProps`:

```
    <TextField 
        InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
      }}
    >...</TextField>
```